# Set shader for single actors

Tags: libgdx

I've started to deal with shaders a bit today and now I'm stuck. I want to apply a shader to certain actors (Images) in a scene2d stage. Is it even possible?
I just have a draw method for the whole scene, but not for single actors oder actor-groups.

Outside a scene2d stage I just would do something like this:

```
batch.setShader(shader);
batch.begin();
batch.draw(Image);
batch.end();
batch.setShader(null);
batch.begin();
```

How to achieve this in a scene2d environment?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you right or not, but you could just do something like `stage.draw()` in between the `setShader()` calls

Comment: Yap, but that's the whole stage then, not a single actor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the shader inside the draw method of an Actor and then change it back (the Batch automatically handles flushing when the shader is changed):

```
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
    batch.setShader(customShader);
    batch.draw(...);
    batch.setShader(null);
}
```

Keep in mind that every time you do this, it will cause the batch to flush. If you have a few dozen actors to draw with the custom shader, you should probably put them in a Group that changes the shader so the batch is only flushed once for the Group:

```
//Custom Group:
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
    batch.setShader(customShader);
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.setShader(null);
}
```

Comment: How do you change the draw method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My examples above would be your own custom subclasses of Actor and Group, respectively.

Comment: Oh okay, that's what I was thinking, I just wasn't sure if it was a valid way of doing it